# What is the correct pronunciation of 唯一

Tags: pronunciation, adverbs, numbers

For the word (or composition of two words): 唯一,
sometimes also written as: 唯一つ,

Two possible pronunciations come to my mind:

- ゆいいつ [*yuiitsu*]　-onyomi

and

- ただ ひとつ [*tada hitotsu*] -kunyomi

**Which one is correct?** Does the last つ in written form make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

唯一 and 唯一つ both work as a *no*-adjective and a standalone adverb, but they are different.

- **唯一** is one word and only read as ゆいいつ in modern Japanese. (ゆいいち is another possible reading according to [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/223584/meaning/m0u/), but I believe you can forget it)
- **唯一つ** (with okurigana つ) is two words, ただひとつ.

They are not always interchangeable. For example you can say 唯一の生存者 ("sole survivor") and 唯【ただ】一人【ひとり】の生存者 but not 唯一つの生存者.